# Stop tty from scrolling down

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, console, tty

I was making some modifications in the linux kernel, and something has broken due to my changes, I have lots of printk's inside the code, which do show up only in the tty console (Ctrl+Alt+F1) .

The problem is that it quickly keeps moving down and reaches the kernel crash info and I cannot determine anything from the crash info as everything is lost after a reset.

Is it somehow possible to make the tty scrollable or even static . By static I mean that it should not scroll down and stay on the original screen even when new messages pop up. (So that I can see my printk's)

Comment: That's what the "Scroll Lock" key was originally designed to do.  But I'm not sure if anything actually supports it these days.

Comment: What are you using for a terminal emulator?  Use a decent one like **minicom**, and simply enable logging to a text file for offline review.  You will then capture everything you type in and everything that gets output to the screen.  Never losing anything, even when you blink or step away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to stop it from scrolling at boot time (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to freeze scrolling, and in fact any updating of the TTY. 
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> to resume.

You can scroll with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>page up</kbd>/<kbd>page down</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command

```
sudo dmesg -n 1
```

to suppress all messages from the kernel (and its drivers) except panic messages from appearing on the console.

To fix at each boot, add the command to:

```
/etc/rc.local
```